# Mandatory Trust Chains are missing in PKCS#12 certificate

Tags: pkcs#12

How to include all CAs Trust Chains (Chain of Trust) in PKCS#12 certificate in C#.NET? I need the solution right from the scratch. I can create a X509 certificate using DOT NET libraries. But I don't know how to include all CAs Trust Chains in PKCS#12 cert format. The trust chains are : Entrust->My CA->My Issuing CA->My Certificate.

Please help me experts.

Answer (score 1):

At first I want to say, I have not worked in C# for some time so at first I want to explain in Java. If you use bouncy castle and the certificates then you can easily build a certificate chain and simply insert the chain. This is a sample java code.

```
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC");
store.load(null, null);
store.setKeyEntry(keyAlias, privKey, null, chain);
FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(fileLocation);
store.store(fOut, password.toCharArray());
```

Now, the certificate chain object **chain** needs to have all the chain certificates. Like:

```
Certificate[] chain = new Certificate[]{(Certificate)childCertificate, (Certificate)subCaCertificate, (Certificate)caCertificate};
```

So, as you can see, the chain should be start from child to mother. Many only insert the child certificate, so full chain does not include during export.

Now, for C#, I want to write some code using bouncycastle. Forgive me if some mistakes happen as I said that, I am not working in C#.
**Sample C# Code**:

```
     Pkcs12Store pkcs12Store = new Pkcs12Store();
     AsymmetricKeyParameter privateKey = ......

     X509CertificateEntry[] certEntry = new X509CertificateEntry[certChain.Count];
     for ( int k = 0; k < certChain.Count; k++ )
     {
         certEntry[k] = new X509CertificateEntry(certChain[k]);
     }
     pkcs12Store.SetKeyEntry (alias, new AsymmetricKeyEntry(privateKey), certEntry);

     MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream ();
     pkcs12Store.Save ( memoryStream, password, GetRandom ( 16 ) );
     byte[] data = memoryStream.GetBuffer ();
     data = Pkcs12Utilities.ConvertToDefiniteLength (data, password);
```

Here, the **certEntry** object will contain all the certificate chain.